# how to close one panel when opening another using Polymer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer

I have an iron-list in which I have a settings icon which, when clicked causes a panel to slide out with settings options in. However when I have one open, I am wanting it to close upon opening the panel for another row. Currently I have it where they can all be open at the same time which is not optimal.

Please see the gif for the problem I am facing.
GIF OF THE PROBLEM 
[image]

**HTML/Polymer**

```
<div class="container horizontal layout">
   <div class="settingsIconContainer">
       <paper-icon-button class="settingIcon" icon="settings" on-click="toggleSettings"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
    <div id="edit" class="settings">
        <paper-icon-button icon="delete"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="create"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="clear" on-click="toggleSettings"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Polymer JS**

```
toggleSettings : function(e) {
    this.$.edit.classList.toggle('settingsMove');
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not access the parent element from the child element. There are two ways of doing this.

1) In the toggle class, fire an event as below

```
toggleSettings : function(e) {
  this.fire('settings-icon-toggle');
}
```

In the parent element add a listener and listen to the fired event.

```
listeners:{
  'settings-icon-toggle': '_onSettingsIconToggle'
},
_onSettingsIconToggle: function(e){
  //Using e.target.id, loop through all the settings and close them except the current one.
}
```

2) Add a boolean property in the object that you're passing to the `iron-list`, pass it to the settins component and set the property to true in the `tolggleSetings` method.

```
toggleSettings : function(e) {
  this._isOpen = false;
}
```

In the Parent component, add an observer to this property and set all the rest of them to false.

```
observers:['_listChanged(arrayToIronList.*)'],
_listChanged:function(){
   var isOpenSubPath = e.path.indexOf('._isOpen')
  if( isOpenSubPath >=0){
    var index = parseInt(e.path.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
    //loop through the array and set all the _isOpen properties to false except the current one. 
    //You can find the current one using the index.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did i misunderstood your question or is this question that simple?

You are trying to have only 1 opened settings at a time, right? so when user presses one settings, all others needs to be closed.

Just find all elements with `settingsMove` class and then remove that class.

```
toggleSettings : function(e) {
    var elems = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll(".settingsMove");
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
      this.toggleClass("settingsMove", false, elems[i]);
    }

    this.toggleClass("settingsMove", true, e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".settings"))
}
```

i don't know what element you need to set class `settingsMove` on. So edit `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".settings"))` to suit your code

I used Polymer native function `toggleClass`. More info you can find here https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-toggleClass